# MVC Razor - Passing a Property to a Model from some HTML without the Controller creating a new Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm a newcomer to MVC (having inherited a razor MVC web site).

I'm trying to get an About Us page to work with a tab style - buttons basically, to flick the content.

I added the following constructor and property ...

```
public class AboutModel
{
    public AboutModel(string selectedAboutTab)
    {
        SelectedAboutTab = selectedAboutTab;
    }
    private string _selectedAboutTab;
    public string SelectedAboutTab
    {
        get { return _selectedAboutTab ?? "about"; }
        set
        {
            _selectedAboutTab = value;
        }
    }
```

and then hoped to use HTML like this to change the tab ...

```
    <a href="/About?selectedAboutTab=directors">directors</a>
```

But it doesn't seem to be passing anything to the Constructor.

I think the problem is in the Home Controller ... which is on the Home Page - that kicks off the AboutModel in the first place ... but I was thinking once I'd navigated from the 'Home Page' to the 'About Us' it's job would be done!  But it actually creates a new Model every time I click on an About 'tab' within the 'About Us' page.

This is the bit of code on the Home Controller.

```
    public virtual ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = MenuPages.About;
        return View(new AboutModel("about"));
    }
```

Sorry for my clear lack of MVC knowledge! but could someone please tell me the easiest way I can get the SelectedAboutTab property populating?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add the selectedAboutTab to the Home Controller ...

```
    public virtual ActionResult About(string selectedAboutTab)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentPage = MenuPages.About;
        return View(new AboutModel(selectedAboutTab));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already answered your own question, but as a general tip, consider using a URL helper rather than hard-coded `<a href />`:

```
@Html.ActionLink( "directors", "About", new { selectedAboutTab = "directors" } )
```

The view engine will dynamically build your link.